# Countdown timer in javafx tableview

Tags: java, javafx

I am struggling to make a countdown timer in javaFX. I want the value of secondenColumn to be used as a timer. So for example when i add row with 'seconden'=200. The timer has to run for 200 seconds (until 0). I don't know how to begin with the code for the timer. This is what i have at the moment...

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener.Change;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class RuniteOre extends Application {

    Stage window;
    TableView<Product> table;
    TextField rockInput, worldInput, aantalSpelers;
    int seconden;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);

    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {





        window = primaryStage;
        window.setTitle("Runite Ore - Calculator");

        //Rock column
        TableColumn<Product, String> rockColumn = new TableColumn<>("Rock");
        rockColumn.setMinWidth(200);
        rockColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("rock"));

        //World column
        TableColumn<Product, Integer> worldColumn = new TableColumn<>("World");
        worldColumn.setMinWidth(100);
        worldColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("world"));

        //Aantal spelers column
        TableColumn<Product, Integer> aantalSpelersColumn = new TableColumn<>("Aantal Spelers");
        aantalSpelersColumn.setMinWidth(100);
        aantalSpelersColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("aantalSpelers"));

        //Seconden column
        //TableColumn<Product, Integer> secondenColumn = new TableColumn<>("Seconden");
        //secondenColumn.setMinWidth(200);
        //secondenColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("seconden"));
        TableView<Product> table = new TableView<>();
        TableColumn<Product, Integer> secondenColumn = new TableColumn<>("Seconden");
        table.getColumns().add(secondenColumn);


        secondenColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().secondsProperty().asObject());
        table.getItems().addListener((Change<? extends Product> c) -> {
            while (c.next()) {
                if (c.wasAdded()) {
                    for (Product item : c.getAddedSubList()) {
                        int startValue = item.getSeconden() ;
                        Timeline countdown = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1), e -> 
                            item.setSeconden(item.getSeconden() - 1)
                        ));
                        countdown.setCycleCount(startValue);
                        countdown.play();
                    }
                }
            }
        }); 




        //Rock input
        rockInput = new TextField();
        rockInput.setPromptText("Rocks");
        rockInput.setMinWidth(100);

        //World input
        worldInput= new TextField();
        worldInput.setPromptText("World");

        //Aantal spelers input
        aantalSpelers = new TextField();
        aantalSpelers.setPromptText("Aantal Spelers");

        //Button
        Button addButton = new Button("Add");
        addButton.setOnAction(e -> addButtonClicked());
        Button deleteButton = new Button("Delete");
        deleteButton.setOnAction(e -> deleteButtonClicked());



        HBox hBox = new HBox();
        hBox.setPadding(new Insets(10,10,10,10));
        hBox.setSpacing(10);
        hBox.getChildren().addAll(rockInput, worldInput, aantalSpelers, addButton, deleteButton);

        table = new TableView<>();
        table.getColumns().addAll(rockColumn, worldColumn, aantalSpelersColumn,secondenColumn);

        VBox vBox = new VBox();
        vBox.getChildren().addAll(table, hBox);

        Scene scene = new Scene(vBox);
        window.setScene(scene);
        window.show();


    }

    //Add button clicked
    public void addButtonClicked(){
        Product product = new Product();
        product.setRock(rockInput.getText());
        product.setWorld(Integer.parseInt(worldInput.getText()));
        product.setAantalSpelers(Integer.parseInt(aantalSpelers.getText()));
        //TESTBEREKENING seconden=(Integer.parseInt(aantalSpelers.getText())*10);
        seconden=(Integer.parseInt(aantalSpelers.getText())*10);
        product.setSeconden(seconden);

        table.getItems().add(product);
        rockInput.clear();
        worldInput.clear();
        aantalSpelers.clear();
    }

    //Delete button clicked
    public void deleteButtonClicked(){
        ObservableList<Product> productSelected, allProducts;
        allProducts = table.getItems();
        productSelected = table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems();

        productSelected.forEach(allProducts::remove);
    }




}
```

and this is the code from class Product:

```
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
public class Product {

    private String rock;
    private int world;
    private int aantalSpelers;
    //private int seconden;
    private int timer;

    private final IntegerProperty seconden = new SimpleIntegerProperty() ;

    public Product(){
        this.rock = "";
        this.world = 0;
        this.aantalSpelers = 0;
    }

    public Product(String rock, int world, int aantalSpelers){
        this.rock = rock;
        this.world = world;
        this.aantalSpelers = aantalSpelers;
    }

    public String getRock() {
        return rock;
    }

    public void setRock(String rock) {
        this.rock = rock;
    }

    public int getWorld() {
        return world;
    }

    public void setWorld(int world) {
        this.world = world;
    }

    public int getAantalSpelers() {
        return aantalSpelers;
    }

    public void setAantalSpelers(int aantalSpelers) {
        this.aantalSpelers = aantalSpelers;
    }

    public final int getSeconden() {
        return secondsProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setSeconden(int seconden) {
        secondsProperty().set(seconden);
    }

    public int getTimer() {
        return timer;
    }

    public void setTimer(int timer) {
        this.timer = timer;
    }



        public Product(int seconden) {
            setSeconden(seconden);
        }

        public IntegerProperty secondsProperty() {
            return seconden ;
        }

}
```

Comment: That Runescape code though :D

Comment: @RileyCarney haha yea but it's actually just for school, i stopped playing rs for years :D

Comment: Ah okay :p I posted an answer down below, was it what you were looking for?

Comment: @RileyCarney thanks but where do i have to put this code? and how can i create a loop?

Comment: Darn, I was hoping this wouldn't be a thing. I'm honestly not familiar with working with javafx, but I'm going to assume it might* loop through the `public void start(Stage primaryStage)`. Try setting `long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();` above `public static void main...` then in the start method do `if (System.currentTimeMillis() - currentTime > 1000) { currentTime += 1000; //and other stuff}`

Comment: It's not really clear to me what you want to see. When a new row is added to the table, `seconden` is a positive integer, right? Are you wanting that actual value to decrease by 1 every second until it is zero? Or are you wanting a countdown starting at that value somewhere else in the table?

Comment: @James_D yes i want the  actual value to decrease by 1 every second. So if i have 3 rows, i should have 3 countdown timers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a `Timeline` and decrease the value once per second every time a new row is added to the table:

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

    // existing code...

    // this just needs to be executed before any rows are added to the table:

    table.getItems().addListener((Change<? extends Product> c) -> {
        while (c.next()) {
            if (c.wasAdded()) {
                for (Product p : c.getAddedSubList()) {
                    int startValue = p.getSeconden();
                    Timeline countdown = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1), 
                        e -> p.setSeconden(p.getSeconden() - 1)));
                    countdown.setCycleCount(startValue);
                    countdown.play();
                }
            }
        }
    });

}
```

This assumes your `Product` class follows the JavaFX properties pattern, i.e. it has a `public IntegerProperty secondenProperty() { ... }` method.

Here is a SSCCE:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener.Change;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextFormatter;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class CountdownTable extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        TableView<Item> table = new TableView<>();
        TableColumn<Item, Integer> secondsCol = new TableColumn<>("Seconds");
        table.getColumns().add(secondsCol);

        secondsCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().secondsProperty().asObject());

        table.getItems().addListener((Change<? extends Item> c) -> {
            while (c.next()) {
                if (c.wasAdded()) {
                    for (Item item : c.getAddedSubList()) {
                        int startValue = item.getSeconds() ;
                        Timeline countdown = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1), e -> 
                            item.setSeconds(item.getSeconds() - 1)
                        ));
                        countdown.setCycleCount(startValue);
                        countdown.play();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        TextField textField = new TextField();
        textField.setPromptText("Type a time in seconds and press enter");
        Pattern integerPattern = Pattern.compile("\\d*");
        TextFormatter<Integer> formatter = new TextFormatter<Integer>( (TextFormatter.Change c) -> {
            String newText = c.getControlNewText();
            if (integerPattern.matcher(newText).matches()) {
                return c ;
            } else {
                return null ;
            }
        });
        textField.setTextFormatter(formatter);

        textField.setOnAction(e -> {
            if (! textField.getText().isEmpty())
            table.getItems().add(new Item(Integer.parseInt(textField.getText())));
            textField.clear();
        });

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(table, null, null, textField, null);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 600, 600));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static class Item {

        private final IntegerProperty seconds = new SimpleIntegerProperty() ;

        public Item(int seconds) {
            setSeconds(seconds);
        }

        public IntegerProperty secondsProperty() {
            return seconds ;
        }

        public final int getSeconds() {
            return secondsProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setSeconds(int seconds) {
            secondsProperty().set(seconds);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
}
```

Comment: i added the code in the class RuniteOre , but now i get the error "non static variable table cannot be referenced from a static context"

Comment: As is pretty clearly shown in the code I posted, you are supposed to put that code in the `start(...)` method, not the `main(...)` method.

Comment: sorry i got confused, but now i get this error 'reference to addListener is ambiguous' :/

Comment: Not clear why you would get that, assuming you copied it correctly this time. I added a complete example that you can copy, paste, and run, for comparison.

Comment: Thanks for the complete example it really helped me. I got rid of the last error, and when i compile i have no syntax errors. But when i click on the button 'Add' the terminal window opens with this:
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at RuniteOre.addButtonClicked(RuniteOre.java:135)
 at RuniteOre.lambda$start$3(RuniteOre.java:101)
...

Comment: I have answered your question. I can't keep debugging every tiny mistake you make. Either accept the answer or don't, but you're going to have to learn to do some things yourself. Debugging a null pointer exception has nothing at all to do with your original question.